# Define which users belong to which host

Tags: ansible

I have an inventory:

```
[dbs]
server1.intranet

[webservices]
server2.intranet

[apps]
server3.intranet
```

And a file with variables:

```
users:
    - { name: user1, ssh_key: <SSH_KEY> }
    - { name: user2, ssh_key: <SSH_KEY> }
```

(1) My first question is: **How can I tell in the inventory which user is part of each server?** (without having to copy and duplicate the user information at every host) Note that users can change and can belong to multiple servers.

(2) The final objective is to do some tasks at each host. For example, to create the users at each host, and add the corresponding user SSH key at each server, something like:

```
- name: SSH
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: "item.name"
    state: present
    key: "item.ssh_key"
    with_items: "{{ users[??] }}"
```

Of course the `users` variable should only have the users for the specific host iterating.

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand your second point, but this solution could be helpful.
Define destination hosts as an array:

```yaml
users:
    - { name: user1, ssh_key: <SSH_KEY>,hosts: ['test-001','test-002'] }
    - { name: user2, ssh_key: <SSH_KEY>,hosts: ['test-002'] }
```

Use `selectattr` filter for your loop to search the running hostname in the hosts list defined in the vars:

```yaml
- name: SSH
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ item.ssh_key }}"
  loop: "{{ users | selectattr('hosts', 'search', inventory_hostname) }}"
```

```yaml
ok: [test-001] => (item={'name': 'user1', 'ssh_key': '<SSH_KEY1>', 'hosts': ['test-001', 'test-002']}) => {
    "msg": "user1"
}
ok: [test-002] => (item={'name': 'user1', 'ssh_key': '<SSH_KEY1>', 'hosts': ['test-001', 'test-002']}) => {
    "msg": "user1"
}
ok: [test-002] => (item={'name': 'user2', 'ssh_key': '<SSH_KEY2>', 'hosts': ['test-002']}) => {
    "msg": "user2"
}
```

Comment: It works but I needed to do some corrections for it to work. I will edit your answer.

Comment: I can't edit but you need to reindent `loop` to the left and place all `item` references between `{{ ... }}`. Please do this change so the answer is correct.

Comment: I saw your edit, but I also needed :  `user: "{{ item.name }}"` and the same for the key

Comment: You're right, I tested it with debug module and just copied your task from the question as I posted the answer.